# Сложить два столбца с помощью LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть таблица в БД

```
table
-----
T1  T2
1   0
2   0
3   1
```

Необходимо получить сразу сумму этих двух столбцов, т.е. 1+2+3+0+0+1=7

В SQL делаю это так:

```
select sum(T1+T2) from table
```

Но как сделать такое с LINQ? Пытаюсь вот так

```
using (cokoEntities context = new cokoEntities())
{
    var result = (from o in context.table
                 select new
                 {
                    sum = o.T2+o.T3
                 }).First();

        Console.WriteLine(result.sum);

}
```

но не выходит. Компилятор выдает отдельные суммы для каждой записи.

Comment: А вариант
context.table.Sum(o=>o.T2+o.T3) 
не работает разве?

Comment: Работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
var summColumn = context.table.Sum(o=>o.T2+o.T3);
```

P.S. ответ из комментария